# Количество вхождений каждого слова в каждое предложение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Задача: во входном потоке дается число - количество предложений, содержащих слова и, возможно, какой-то разделяющий мусор; после числа на каждой строке расположены сами предложения; далее дается число - количество ключевых слов; после него на каждой строке расположены сами слова.

Нужно найти количество вхождений каждого ключевого слова в каждое предложение.

Определение слова:

> A word made of a series of letters ( lower or upper ) or numerics or
>   an underscore _ ( ascii value 95).
>
> We define a substring as follows.
>
> It is a part of a word.
>   The given substring must be preceded and succeeded by letters or numerics or an underscore. A word will be surrounded by 1 or more occurrences of non-letter, non-numeric and non-underscore ( not an underscore ) characters - or the beginning or end of a line on one side.

Можно ли улучшить мой код? Сделать его короче и эффективнее по количеству операций. Может быть, при помощи функционального программирования можно сократить все это раза в два? Перл к этому располагает.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

chomp(my $lines_count = <>);    # read the number of centences
my @words;
for (1..$lines_count)
{
        my $line = <>;
        push @words, split /[^\w]/, $line;
}

my $pattern_count = <>;
for (1..$pattern_count)
{
        chomp(my $input = <>);
        my $result = 0;
        foreach (@words)
        {
                if (/\w+$input\w+/)
                {
                        $result++;
                }
        }
        print $result, "\n";
}
```

> Sample Input
>
> 1 existing pessimist optimist this is 1 is
>
> Sample Output
>
> 3
>
> Explanation
>
> 'existing' has 'is' as a substring and is both preceded and succeeded by words as defined above.
>
> 'pessimist' has 'is' as a substring for the same argument as above.
>
> 'optimist' has 'is' as a substring for the same argument as above.
>
> 'this' though has 'is' as a substring is only preceded by a word and is succeeded by a [blank space] which is non-letter, non-numeric
>   and non-underscore
>
> ```
> 'is' is not included as it is preceded and succeeded by a [blank space] which is non-letter, non-numeric and non-underscore.
> ```

Comment: А растолкуйте фразу "Нужно найти количество вхождений каждого ключевого слова в каждое предложение.". Это общее количество ключа во всем тексте в целом или в каждом предложении по отдельности. И кстати `+` в `/\w+$input`абсолютно ни к чему, достаточно убедится, что перед и после $input стоит \w

Comment: Добавил объяснение в конец. Одно слово ищется во всех предложениях. Количество совпадений суммируется. Потом переходим к следующему ключу.

Comment: А какое отношение perl имеет к функциональному программированию ? Функциональное программирование на сколько я понимаю совершено другая парадигма, для которой есть свои языки ...

Comment: В перл можно использовать функциональыне фичи. И в си можно, если самому реализовать недостающее. ФП позволяет кое-что писать короче, чем на императивных языках.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
chomp(my $lines_count = <>);      # read the number of centences
my $text="";
$text.=<> for (1..$lines_count);  # Собираем весь входной текст в единую строку
my $pattern_count = <>;
for (1..$pattern_count)
{
        chomp(my $input = <>);
        print $text=~s/(\w$input\w)/$1/g, "\n";
}
```

Главная строчка это конечно print. В нем мы делаем замену подходящих участков текста на саму себя. Оператор замены `=~s///` возвращает количество произведенных замен, таким образом он возвращает как раз количество мест, где встретилась подстрока.

В принципе можно еще сильнее укоротить, но смысл написанного начинает ускользать ...:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $text=join('',map {$_=<>} 1..<>);
print map {chomp($_=<>); $text=~s/\w$_\w/$&/g, "\n"} 1..<>;
```